# Creating an Excel file with a table using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I am trying to create an Excel file with NodeJS where the data in the sheet is a table. Perhaps it's how I'm wording it, but I cannot for the life of me find a way to do this.

I've tried using libraries ([excel4node](https://github.com/natergj/excel4node), [exceljs](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs), [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)) and none of them seem to support inserting values into a spreadsheet as a table. Just to clarify, I have no issues just adding ranges to the spreadsheet. The issue is specifically adding them as an [Excel Table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c), or converting the range to a table afterwards. I imagined a solution similar to [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML), where you can [pass a DataTable](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Adding-DataTable-as-Worksheet) and it'll add the data to a worksheet as a table

Am I missing something incredibly basic here? I feel like this should be a super simple solution.

Comment: Does [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-tables) help?

Comment: @BruceWayne unfortunately not. That documentation refers to Excel add-ins, which (how I understand it) is more like Excel macros

EDIT: Actually, it says it can be hosted on its own. I'll have to look into this more

Comment: As I originally thought, add-ins are used as extensions of the Excel application itself. So this is a no-go.